# Pandoc citeproc bibliography entries sorting follows the order of entries in bib file

Tags: pandoc, csl, pandoc-citeproc

When I convert the markdown file to pdf the order of references in the bibliography is the same as in the `.bib` file.  As a result, the references in the text appear in the wrong order.  As a result, I can have in the text sentences like `... reported in [2] after [1] ...`  while I would like the references to be sorted in the bibliography as they appear in the text, as it would be using `unsrt.bib`.

The question is: how do I achieve sorting of entries in the bibliography section in order of their appearance in the text?

MWE, compiled using `pandoc -C -f markdown testing.md -o testing.pdf`

**testing.md:**

```
---
bibliography: test.bib
csl: aps.csl
---

The first reference [@second_title_2015]

The second reference [@author_title_2014]
```

**test.bib**

```
@article{author_title_2014,
  title = {The title},
  author = {Author, A. B. and Other, C. D.},
  year = {2014},
}

@article{second_title_2015,
  title = {The other title},
  author = {Second, T. A. and First, F. G.},
  year = {2015},
}
```

The output

[image: Illustration of the order of the references]

Changing the order of `@article`'s in `test.bib` results in the desired output: `The first reference [1] the second reference [2]`.

I am using the `aps.csl` taken from zotero style repository:
https://www.zotero.org/styles/american-physics-society?source=1

**cause of the problem**:

I had an outdated pandoc installed by conda (pandoc is a prerequisite for some important packages I needed), and this version took precedence over the default arch installation because of conda's executables dir being in `$PATH` before `/bin/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use outdated pandoc? I tested your code with pandoc 2.13, which produced the correct output. You can get the latest release [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases).

```sh
pandoc --version
pandoc 2.13
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.22, texmath 0.12.2, skylighting 0.10.5,
citeproc 0.3.0.9, ipynb 0.1.0.1

pandoc -C -f markdown testing.md -o testing.pdf
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I did.   Whoever runs into the same problem: I had an outdated pandoc installed by conda (pandoc is a prerequisite for some important packages I needed), and this version took precedence over the default arch installation because of conda's executables dir being in `$PATH` before `/bin/.